# What are the Formal Names and Terms of the UI elements in CRM 2011?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I'm trying to find a listing of the different CRM 2011 UI elements and not finding any.  There is the Ribbon, and the main form, and the sections and groups, and don't forget the left side navigation.  Surly there is a picture somewhere with the different ui elements highlighted, along with their names?

### Edit

The SDK isn't that helpful.  Here is the Layout listing for Forms:
[image]

Comment: for who downvoted or asked to close this question: from stackoverflow help (http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) permitted questions are also "practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession". I hope that they will write "the left part of the form" instead "Navigation Panel" inside their next document of a Dynamics CRM project, the customer will be very happy about.

Answer (score 3):

You can check the `User Interface Design Guide for Microsoft Dynamics CRM` included inside the SDK.

The path is

```
resources\styleguide\default.htm
```

Comment: What use the SDK?  How Scandalous!